# Rust - Failed to create package

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm following the basic steps here: file:///Users/leongaban/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/share/doc/rust/html/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html

I checked my cargo version, and `cd ..` back up to my root project folders and ran the following command to create a new project:

```
cargo new hello_cargo
```

And it threw the following error:

> error: Failed to create package `hello_cargo` at `/Users/leongaban/projects/rust_projects/hello_cargo`

However when I run `ls` it did create the folder? So I'm curious how do I avoid that error in the future?

```
rust_projects % cargo new hello_cargo
error: Failed to create package `hello_cargo` at `/Users/leongaban/projects/rust_projects/hello_cargo`

Caused by:
  could not find '/Users/leongaban/.git-templates/' to stat: No such file or directory; class=Os (2); code=NotFound (-3)
rust_projects % ls
hello_cargo hello_world
```

Comment: By default cargo tries to create a Git repository in the project. If you don't need it, just run `cargo new --vcs none hello_cargo`.

Comment: Or install git, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe caused by `git init` command invoked when you run `cargo new`, [the source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/e4b65bdc80f2a293447f2f6a808fa7c84bf9a357/src/cargo/ops/cargo_new.rs#L597) is as below:

```rust
if !path.join(".git").exists() {
    // Temporary fix to work around bug in libgit2 when creating a
    // directory in the root of a posix filesystem.
    // See: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/5130
    paths::create_dir_all(path)?;
    GitRepo::init(path, config.cwd())?;
}
```

And the `.git-templates` is documented under `git init` [TEMPLATE DIRECTORY](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory) section.

**The template directory will be one of the following (in order):**

> 1. the argument given with the --template option;
> 2. the contents of the $GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR environment variable;
> 3. the init.templateDir configuration variable; or
> 4. the default template directory: /usr/share/git-core/templates.

So you should check above 4 possible cause to setup the non-exists folder  `'/Users/leongaban/.git-templates/'` as git tempalte dir when run `git init`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. My environment:

```
  System: MacOS Catalina (version: 10.15.7)
  Rustc version: rustc 1.51.0
```

Solution:

1. `rustup self install`
2. `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`

Answer (score 0):

I had a template defined in my gitconfig

```
[init]
        templatedir = /Users/johndye/.git-templates
```

I am not sure when this got added or why but commenting it out got me past this error